# Prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\int_{-1}^{1}{f(x)(1-x^2)^n}dx}{\int_{-1}^{1}{(1-x^2)^n}dx}=f(0)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

Prove that:Let $f\in C[-1,1]$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\int_{-1}^{1}{f(x)(1-x^2)^n}dx}{\int_{-1}^{1}{(1-x^2)^n}dx}=f(0)$$

My attempt:

$$\begin{eqnarray}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\int_{-1}^{1}{f(x)(1-x^2)^n}dx}{\int_{-1}^{1}{(1-x^2)^n}dx}=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\int_{0}^{1}{f(x)+f(-x)(1-x^2)^n}dx}{2\int_{0}^{1}{(1-x^2)^n}dx}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(f(\xi)+f(-\xi))(\int_{0}^{1}{1-x^2)^n}dx}{2\int_{0}^{1}{(1-x^2)^n}dx}
\end{eqnarray}$$
But I can't complete this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a standard argument dealing with this type of problem, often known as [*approximation-to-the-identity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#nascent_delta_function). Here is a slightly general claim, which does not harm the essence of the argument.

> **Proposition.** Let $K_n \in C([-1,1])$ and assume that $(K_n)$ satisfy the following assumtions:
>
> 1. *Nonnegativity.* $K_n(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in [-1, 1]$ and $n \geq 1$.
> 2. *Normalization.* $\int_{-1}^{1} K_n(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = 1$ for all $n \geq 1$.
> 3. *Concentration.* For any $\delta > 0$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{|x|>\delta} K_n(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = 0$.
>
> Then for any $f \in C([-1, 1])$, we have
> $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{-1}^{1} f(x)K_n(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = f(0). $$

In other words, $K_n(x)$ approximates the Dirac delta $\delta(x)$, which is "the identity" of the convolution (hence the name approximation-to-the-identity). Before the proof, let us check that this can be applicable to OP's problem. Indeed, set

$$K_n(x) = \frac{(1-x^2)^n}{\int_{-1}^{1} (1-t^2)^n \, \mathrm{d}t}. $$

Then the conditions 1 and 2 are obvious. For the concentration, notice that $(1 - t^2)^n \geq (1 - |t|)^n$, and so,

$$ \int_{|x|>\delta} K_n(x) \, \mathrm{d}t
\leq \frac{(1 - \delta^2)^n}{\int_{0}^{1}(1 - t)^n \, \mathrm{d}t} = (n+1)(1 - \delta^2)^n \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0. $$

Therefore $\int_{-1}^{1} f(x)K_n(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \to f(0)$ by the conclusion of the proposition.

---

*Proof of Proposition.* For any $\epsilon > 0$, find $\delta > 0$ so that $|x| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - f(0)| < \epsilon$. Also, choose a bound $M > 0$ of $f$. Then

\begin{align*}
\left| \int_{-1}^{1} f(x)K_n(x) \, \mathrm{d}x - f(0) \right|
&\leq \int_{-1}^{1} |f(x) - f(0)|K_n(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_{|x|<\delta} |f(x) - f(0)|K_n(x) \, \mathrm{d}x + \int_{|x|\geq\delta} |f(x) - f(0)|K_n(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&\leq \int_{-1}^{1} \epsilon K_n(x) \, \mathrm{d}x + \int_{|x|\geq\delta} 2M K_n(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \epsilon + 2M \int_{|x|\geq\delta} K_n(x) \, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}

So we have

$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} \left| \int_{-1}^{1} f(x)K_n(x) \, \mathrm{d}x - f(0) \right| \leq \epsilon. $$

But since the left-hand side a fixed number independent of $\epsilon$ and the right-hand side can be made arbitrarily small, letting $\epsilon \downarrow 0$ proves the desired claim. $\square$

Comment: So good!You gave a more general approach

Answer (score 4):

Let $x=y/\sqrt n.$ The expression becomes

$$\frac{\int_{-\sqrt n}^{\sqrt n}f(y/\sqrt n)(1-y^2/n)^n\,dy}{\int_{-\sqrt n}^{\sqrt n}(1-y^2/n)^n\,dy}.$$

Now $(1-y^2/\sqrt n)^n\le e^{-y^2}$ on $[-\sqrt n,\sqrt n].$ And $f$ is bounded. Also note that for fixed $y,$ $f(y/\sqrt n) \to f(0)$ by the continuity of $f$ at $0.$ It follows from the DCT that the limit is

$$\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(0)e^{-y^2}\, dy}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-y^2}\, dy} = f(0).$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\lim_{n \to \infty}{\int_{-1}^{1}\mrm{f}\pars{x}
\pars{1 - x^{2}}^{n}\,\dd x \over
\int_{-1}^{1}\pars{1 - x^{2}}^{n}\,\dd x}} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}{\int_{0}^{1}
\bracks{\mrm{f}\pars{x} + \mrm{f}\pars{-x}}
\pars{1 - x^{2}}^{n}\,\dd x \over
2\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - x^{2}}^{n}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\,\lim_{n \to \infty}{\int_{0}^{1}
\bracks{\mrm{f}\pars{x} + \mrm{f}\pars{-x}}
\expo{n\ln\pars{1 - x^{2}}}\,\dd x \over
\int_{0}^{1}\expo{n\ln\pars{1 - x^{2}}}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\,\lim_{n \to \infty}{\int_{0}^{\infty}
\bracks{\mrm{f}\pars{0} + \mrm{f}\pars{-0}}
\expo{-nx^{2}}\,\dd x \over
\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-nx^{2}}\,\dd x}
\end{align}

> The last step involves the
> [Laplace's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method) which requires some $\ds{\mrm{f}\pars{x}}$ 'nice conditions' as you can see in the above link: I already assumed that's the case.

$$
\mbox{Then},\quad
\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\lim_{n \to \infty}{\int_{-1}^{1}\mrm{f}\pars{x}
\pars{1 - x^{2}}^{n}\,\dd x \over
\int_{-1}^{1}\pars{1 - x^{2}}^{n}\,\dd x}} = \bbx{\mrm{f}\pars{0}}
$$